# Errors when using Sqoop action in Oozie editor (Hue)

Tags: hadoop, oozie, sqoop, hue

I am trying to use Sqoop action in Oozie editor in Hue, however I can't get it to work.

Here's what I have tried so far.

I put everything in arguments, instead of command (http://alvincjin.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/create-sqoop-action-in-oozie-using-hue.html)

Further, I am trying to connect to Teradata, so I've placed the jdbc jars in HDFS and have added them in Files.
This is what the current workflow looks like in the editor:
[Sqoop Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVodr.png)
.

The workflow definition is:

```
<workflow-app name="Sqoop_test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="sqoop-b20d"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="sqoop-b20d">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>development</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.name</name>
                    <value>test_sqoop</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.task.timeout</name>
                    <value>0</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
              <arg>import</arg>
              <arg>--connect</arg>
              <arg>jdbc:teradata://XXXXX</arg>
              <arg>--query</arg>
              <arg>select count(*) from XXXXX</arg>
              <arg>--fetch-size</arg>
              <arg>10000</arg>
              <arg>--num-mappers</arg>
              <arg>1</arg>
              <arg>--hive-table-name</arg>
              <arg>XXXXX.tmp_sqoop_test</arg>
              <arg>--hive-import</arg>
              <arg>--hive-overwrite</arg>
              <arg>--target-dir</arg>
              <arg>/user/dXXXXX/digital/test/tmp_sqoop_test</arg>
              <arg>--username</arg>
              <arg>XXXXX</arg>
              <arg>--password</arg>
              <arg>XXXXX</arg>
            <file>/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/digital/lib/terajdbc4.jar#terajdbc4.jar</file>
            <file>/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/digital/lib/teradata-connector-1.3.4-hadoop220.jar#teradata-connector-1.3.4-hadoop220.jar</file>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

However, I get this error:

```
2016-01-06 14:13:52,114 ERROR [main] tool.BaseSqoopTool (BaseSqoopTool.java:hasUnrecognizedArgs(296)) - Error parsing arguments for import:
2786 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Unrecognized argument: --hive-table-name
2016-01-06 14:13:52,114 ERROR [main] tool.BaseSqoopTool (BaseSqoopTool.java:hasUnrecognizedArgs(299)) - Unrecognized argument: --hive-table-name
2786 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Unrecognized argument: XXXXX.tmp_sqoop_test
2016-01-06 14:13:52,114 ERROR [main] tool.BaseSqoopTool (BaseSqoopTool.java:hasUnrecognizedArgs(299)) - Unrecognized argument: tdcprdr_app_digital.tmp_sqoop_test
2786 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Unrecognized argument: --hive-import
2016-01-06 14:13:52,114 ERROR [main] tool.BaseSqoopTool (BaseSqoopTool.java:hasUnrecognizedArgs(299)) - Unrecognized argument: --hive-import
2786 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Unrecognized argument: --hive-overwrite
2016-01-06 14:13:52,114 ERROR [main] tool.BaseSqoopTool (BaseSqoopTool.java:hasUnrecognizedArgs(299)) - Unrecognized argument: --hive-overwrite
2787 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
2016-01-06 14:13:52,115 ERROR [main] tool.BaseSqoopTool (BaseSqoopTool.java:hasUnrecognizedArgs(299)) - Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
...
```

I was under the impression that this error can be resolved by placing everything in arguments.
The same code works when run through a shell script. I've tried placing the import command and connection string in command section, but that doesn't even run. I've tried creating a minimalistic sqoop action as well, with just the query and connect statement as follows:

```
<workflow-app name="Sqoop_minimal" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="sqoop-eeeb"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="sqoop-eeeb">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
              <arg>import</arg>
              <arg>--connect</arg>
              <arg>jdbc:teradata://tdXXXXX</arg>
              <arg>--query</arg>
              <arg>select count(*) from XXXXX</arg>
              <arg>--target-dir</arg>
              <arg>/user/dXXXXX/digital/test/tmp_sqoop_test</arg>
              <arg>--username</arg>
              <arg>XXXXX</arg>
              <arg>--password</arg>
              <arg>XXXXX</arg>
            <file>/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/digital/lib/teradata-connector-1.3.4-hadoop220.jar#teradata-connector-1.3.4-hadoop220.jar</file>
            <file>/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/digital/lib/terajdbc4.jar#terajdbc4.jar</file>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

With this workflow, I get a very vague error as follows:

```
>>> Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>

2287 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
2016-01-06 14:57:48,381 WARN  [main] tool.SqoopTool (SqoopTool.java:loadPluginsFromConfDir(175)) - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
2324 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5.3.0.0.0-249
2016-01-06 14:57:48,418 INFO  [main] sqoop.Sqoop (Sqoop.java:<init>(92)) - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5.3.0.0.0-249
2339 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
2016-01-06 14:57:48,433 WARN  [main] tool.BaseSqoopTool (BaseSqoopTool.java:applyCredentialsOptions(1014)) - Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
```

The Oozie version is 4.1.0.3.0.0.0-249.

I've tried searching for a solution online, but no luck. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Already seen and tried the links:

```
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Sqoop-fails-with-quot-Error-parsing-arguments-for-import-quot/td-p/31930

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770698/sqoop-free-form-query-causing-unrecognized-arguments-in-hue-oozie
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such argumnets for sqoop
--hive-table-name 
use
--hive-table. It should not show Unrecognized argument now

Comment: Thank you! I changed the option to "hive-table", and it worked, i.e. to some extent. It now shows an error    "2417 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string: jdbc:teradata://XXXXX/LOGMECH=TD2
". I have already placed the teradata connector jar in Oozie's share lib directory, and have also specified this property in sqoop action: sqoop.connection.factories=com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory,com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.TeradataManagerFactory.

Comment: In job.properties you need to mention oozie.use.system.libpath=true